# 20.04LTS NetworkManager VPN - Always on

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a working VPN connection setup in Ubuntu 20.04LTS.
How do I setup such that it auto connects when the wifi is connected to a specific SSID?

For example, i always frequent "This_wifi_network".
I would like the VPN to auto turn on when wifi is connect to this public network.

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Open the hidden Network Connection Editor

There is a hidden app that does not show when you search for it. To open this app, open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
nm-connection-editor
```

This will open the Network Connection Editor as below:

[image]

1. Select your WiFi Network
2. Click on the Settings "cog" icon below

See the picture below for the next screen:

[image]

1. Select the **General** tab
2. Check the box next to **Automatically connect to VPN when using this connecion**
3. Select the VPN from the drop-down menu below.
4. Click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button below to save the changes.

## Unhide Network Connection Editor

To make Network Connection Editor show up in applications searches in Gnome, do the following:

Go to `/usr/share/applications` and find the icon for “Network Connections”. Right click and edit as administrator. Comment out the line:  `NotShowIn=KDE;GNOME;` to:

```
#NotShowIn=KDE;GNOME;
```

Now it will show up in the “Show Application”

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much! This works. I wonder why this setting is hidden, it's so useful!