# Network Manager crash out of nowhere Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, crash

Basically, once in a while, the Network Manager dies out of nowhere.
The computer still seems connected to the wifi but it says there is no connection to the internet;
When I try to open the wifi settings I get the "Oops, something has gone wrong. Please contact your software vendor. NetworkManager needs to be running".
Moreover, everything looks incredibly slow, When I try to run any sudo command in the terminal to try to restart the network manager it just does nothing and let me in "blank space" in the terminal.
Plus I can't turn off the computer from the Power off/Log Out option, and I have to restart it from the mechanical button.
Once restarted it works, but it's extremely annoying and unpredictable, plus, working on cloud systems, it causes me to lose stuff most of the times it happens.

Comment: Me too, with all the same symptoms. If it helps it happens when I'm on an external gpu dock using ethernet through it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue/symptoms two weeks ago, when I changed apartment and my computer was connecting to a new router.

I solved it by updating my kernel to the latest mainline. Since then I did not have any issue again (until now).

You can find alternative ways to update your kernel here:
https://linuxhint.com/update_ubuntu_kernel_20_04/

Comment: Updating to the mainline kernels might not be a suitable solution to everyone. Updating to the HWE kernels on the other hand is a more viable solution if the problem is suspected to be driver related.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to ubuntu linux and had the same problem. At first I didn't have any network connection - no wifi and no wired connections. The fix for wifi connection problem was to remove unnecessary character from wifi powersave options file.
To open the file run:

`sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

The file should contain only the following:

> [connection]
> wifi.powersave = 3

The wired connection problem got fixed when I rewrote the content in the following file.
To open it run:

`sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`

The file content which I used to fix the issue:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you change anything in that .yaml file?  That appears to be the default content in my 20.04 distro.